# Satellites - predominant apparent motion?

Tags: artificial-satellite, low-earth-orbit, starlink

Recently, while foolin’ around with Stellarium, and checking out its simulation capabilities, I recorded some satellite activity.

Sped up ~30x, here are about 12 minutes of simulated sky on March 31, 2022, around 17:38 (-7 utc), viewed from Juneau, Alaska, with FOV ~centered on Procyon (Orion on the upper right).

[image: satellites on Stellarium simulation]

Almost all of the moving objects in this video simulation appear to move from west to east, and somewhat north to south.

**Probably a very simple answer to this question, but why are there so few objects (satellites) that appear to move east to west, or south to north?**

Update:

Based on the responses from Nuclear Hoagie and JohnHoltz, here are what I believe are the same satellites, at different points in their orbits, viewed from approximately Juneau’s antipode.

Sped up ~30x, here are about 8 minutes of simulated sky on March 31, 2022, around 16:54 (-8 utc), FOV ~centered on Altair.

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Launching west to east requires less fuel.**

An object in low earth orbit is moving horizontally at around 8km/s. Launching a satellite in the west-east direction allows you to take advantage of the earth's natural rotation. The earth's rotational speed is about 0.45km/s at the equator (from west to east), so a satellite launched toward the east from the equator only needs to gain 7.55km/s of additional speed rather than 8km/s. Launching it to the west would make it even harder to get to orbit, as you'd need to change velocity by 8.45km/s.

Incidentally, this is why many spaceports tend to be as near the equator as is practical while remaining in their home countries (US spaceports, for example, are located toward the south, in Texas, Florida, and southern California). The linear rotation speed at the equator is 0.45km/s but the linear speed decreases as you go further from the equator, going to 0km/s at the poles. Launching toward the east from the near equator allows you to get some of the horizontal speed needed for orbit completely "for free".

Comment: +1 for the west-to-east answer. You could add that North-to-South satellites become South-to-North once they cross over the pole. A longer time frame is needed to average out the polar orbits.

Comment: Is it a linear decrease in speed gained, or is it the sine / cosine / another function of the latitude?

Comment: @Tim:  it is the cosine of the latitude if you launch due east.  That puts you in an orbit inclined to the equator by your latitude in the approximation that the maneuvers to get in orbit are done quickly compared to one day.

Comment: @JohnHoltz You must have observed a particular constellation. The proportions between north-south and south-north will be mostly equal on the average; specifically a satellite moving northwest to southeast, a couple hours later will appear to move northeast to southwest as you move under its "return" part of the orbit.

Comment: @ SF - I believe starlink satellites complete an orbit in about 90 minutes, so for them, it’s about 45 minutes for this apparent change in direction.

Comment: The California spaceport isn't for the rotational boost, it's for the ability to go for a polar or retrograde orbit while still having decent weather (launching west from Vandenberg means dropping spent stages on places like Los Angeles and Phoenix; launching polar from the Cape or Texas means dropping stages on Cuba and Mexico).  The best location for a high-inclination launch site would be northern Alaska, since you have less rotation to cancel out, but Alaska's weather isn't conducive to frequent launches.

Comment: @Tim A linear function would require anomalous behavior at the equator (the slope of the speed-versus-latitude graph would have to instantaneously reverse sign). We should expect the slope in reality to instead smoothly approach zero at the equator (to see why it should be zero, consider what would happen if we had a cylinder tangent to the Earth at the equator: by symmetry, all locations should have the same linear speed) , and then smoothly reverse direction.

Comment: @BruceS It's not about their orbital period - it's about your position in relation to their orbit; I purposefully neglected the orbital period as insignificantly short in relation to that. For a satellite in polar orbit, it will take you 12h to travel from underneath its "north-south" route to "south-north". Similarly, on the equator, any inclined orbit will take you 12h of travel. For arbitrary inclinations the period will be shorter as you "cut" a shorter piece off the ellipse, or you can even observe a reversal of direction if you're at latitude close to the sat's inclination.

Comment: @SF - important clarification, thank you.